# usage of jquery .live() to work with both present and future DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've my jQuery code as

```
$('#tarea').click(function() {
     // Do stuffs
});
```

This works fine for the button #tarea loaded along with this script. If the button #tarea had been loaded using ajax in future, than the above code doesn't work.

Now I changed the code to

```
$('#tarea').live('click', function() {
     // Do stuffs
});
```

This time, the button #tarea if loaded along with the script doesn't work. But the script works with the button if generated using ajax.

How do I write the script so that in both cases, it works??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.live()` works in both cases without doing anything additional to what you have already done.  I would check for some other problems in your code that might be preventing this from happening.

**Important:** One thing to check is to make sure that your `.live()` event is being bound and that it doesn't rely on some other event happening. It might help to post the important parts of you JavaScript file. Personally I like to declare my `.live()` events globally.

I do something like this:

```
// this is what I mean by global because it is outside the document.ready
$("#test").live("click", function() {
    // do stuff
});

$(function() {
    // do stuff when document is ready
});
```

If you want to prove what I said above, you only need to put the button and the `.live()` JavaScript code in a new HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

You put :

```
$('#tarea').click(function() {
     // Do stuffs
});
```

in a function.

And when you load via ajax, you add a callback function (the one above) in second parameter of .load()

For example :

```
.load(target_url, function() { $('#tarea').click(function() { blablabla; }})
```